# Как сделать проверку на max-width в jQuery?

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно чтобы скрипт выполнялся только тогда, когда ширине окна выше заданного значения. Как это сделать?
Код, который нужно выполнять:

```js
  var cw = $('.slider').height();
  $('.nav').css({
    'max-height': cw + 'px'
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Все просто, попробуй:

```js
//Inicialize at start
if ($(window).width() > 500) {
  //Active
  var cw = $('.slider').height();
  $('.nav').css({
    'height': cw + 'px'
  });
}
else {
  //Some active when width of browser window less than 500
}


//Activities with resize window
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 500) {
    //Active
    var cw = $('.slider').height();
    $('.nav').css({
      'height': cw + 'px'
    });
  }
  else {
        $('.nav').css({
      'height': 40 + 'px'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
    .slider {
      height: 80px;
      width: 80px;
      background-color: black;
    }

    .nav {
      height: 40px;
      width: 80px;
      background-color:orange;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
</div>  

<div class="nav">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

можно вот так

```
if ($(window).width() > 'значение') {
     var cw = $('.slider').height();
     $('.nav').css({
       'max-height': cw + 'px'
     });
}
```

Comment: А как ширину указать здесь? что-то не срабатывает

Comment: поправил ответ, попробуйте

Comment: Я конечно дико извиняюсь но height - это высота, ширина будет width.

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk, да, конечно, так и есть

Comment: просто вас спрашивали про ширину а вы показывали про высоту ))

Comment: Наглая бездумная копия моего ответа, с другого вопроса. Даже название переменных не поменял: [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554198/Как-сделать-блоки-одинаковой-высоты/554208#554208)

Comment: @NikitaSmith, вопрос на который вы отвечали тоже был скопирован? вместе с именами переменных? Я отвечал на конкретный вопрос в котором и были указаны имена данных переменных!